# mapping geo points on picture map

Tags: python, geometry, mapbox, geospatial, geojson

have a picture map like below:

[image]

and i have a list of points that i wanna map them in this png map
i know the bounding box of the picture:
[52.00198088, 35.66569172, 52.08012633, 35.74706129]

how can i put my points on below map?

i mean how to convert lat/long to pixel?

the picture size is 600x600

i just divide the difference of min and max points to 600 but the result picture is not correct:

[image]

can any one help me????

Answer (score 1):

Hı,

Here is the procedure ...

You know the bounding box of picture ... Follow the steps below

1. Convert the top left corner latitude and longitude to UTM (easting and northing). In python its very easy just use [UTM](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) library to convert. This is now in meters.
2. Now if you know the resolution of your pixel i.e. how many meters per pixel is image, then know many pixels you have to move.
3. Moving in right direction you have to add the meters per pixel in easting to top left corner and moving down you have to subtract the meters per pixel in northing.
4. If you have some point in map in Lat and long and you want to go there then just convert that point also in UTM (easting, northing) and just using Pythagoras theorem find how many pixels you have to move in left and down direction.

That it. If you need more help I can explain more ...

Good Luck

Comment: what if my picture be in multiple utm zone ?

Comment: Its such a small picture. You must be knowing that its is in one zone. Even for such small picture maximum it will be in two zones and it can be handled also

Comment: could you have a look at https://gitlab.com/pixozeus/geo/-/blob/master/utm
and i also don't know hot yo use Pythagoras theorem to find the right pixel for my points

Comment: At your https://gitlab.com/pixozeus/geo/-/blob/master/utm the x_position  and y_position you calculated are the delata_x and delta_y. After this step you have to add this to top_x and top_y to get the final position. If you like the answer please accept the answer and make it useful.

Comment: x_position and y_position is on pixel unit but if i add top_x and top_y to them i will changed, i need pixel to find the right position on the picture

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Good luck dear

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add you code?

If your bounding box is correct the below code from [Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/) would do what you like in JS. Just replace the image URL with yours, and specify the correct bounding box.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add an image</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
    var mapStyle = {
        'version': 8,
        'name': 'Dark',
        'sources': {
            'mapbox': {
                'type': 'vector',
                'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8'
            },
            'overlay': {
                'type': 'image',
                'url': 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif',
                'coordinates': [
                    [-80.425, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 37.936],
                    [-80.425, 37.936]
                ]
            }
        },
        'sprite': 'mapbox://sprites/mapbox/dark-v10',
        'glyphs': 'mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf',
        'layers': [
            {
                'id': 'background',
                'type': 'background',
                'paint': { 'background-color': '#111' }
            },
            {
                'id': 'water',
                'source': 'mapbox',
                'source-layer': 'water',
                'type': 'fill',
                'paint': { 'fill-color': '#2c2c2c' }
            },
            {
                'id': 'boundaries',
                'source': 'mapbox',
                'source-layer': 'admin',
                'type': 'line',
                'paint': {
                    'line-color': '#797979',
                    'line-dasharray': [2, 2, 6, 2]
                },
                'filter': ['all', ['==', 'maritime', 0]]
            },
            {
                'id': 'overlay',
                'source': 'overlay',
                'type': 'raster',
                'paint': { 'raster-opacity': 0.85 }
            },
            {
                'id': 'cities',
                'source': 'mapbox',
                'source-layer': 'place_label',
                'type': 'symbol',
                'layout': {
                    'text-field': '{name_en}',
                    'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Bold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                    'text-size': [
                        'interpolate',
                        ['linear'],
                        ['zoom'],
                        4,
                        9,
                        6,
                        12
                    ]
                },
                'paint': {
                    'text-color': '#969696',
                    'text-halo-width': 2,
                    'text-halo-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)'
                }
            },
            {
                'id': 'states',
                'source': 'mapbox',
                'source-layer': 'place_label',
                'type': 'symbol',
                'layout': {
                    'text-transform': 'uppercase',
                    'text-field': '{name_en}',
                    'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Bold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                    'text-letter-spacing': 0.15,
                    'text-max-width': 7,
                    'text-size': [
                        'interpolate',
                        ['linear'],
                        ['zoom'],
                        4,
                        10,
                        6,
                        14
                    ]
                },
                'filter': ['==', ['get', 'class'], 'state'],
                'paint': {
                    'text-color': '#969696',
                    'text-halo-width': 2,
                    'text-halo-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)'
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        maxZoom: 5.99,
        minZoom: 4,
        zoom: 5,
        center: [-75.789, 41.874],
        style: mapStyle
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

For mapbox you can use their static image API

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/static-maps/

Use the playground to test out how the generated URL looks

https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/

As an example the following kotlin code places pins and routes on maps

https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/services/mapbox/mapbox.kt

https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/commands/uberprices.kts

n.b. you need an appropriate commercial Uber access token to run the code.

Comment: this will not help me because i need custom marker icon and i should be able to replace mapbox map with other maps api, so i need to find a way to do it manually by code

Comment: This response does not answer this question. Maybe another one..

Comment: The original example is using mapbox images. This is the official way to do what the OP is asking. If it doesn't suit and they want to do it all manually then sure.  But I've done exactly what OP is asking using above API and it's trivial code to write.